# Hide folder in .htaccess, but allow directory listing

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

So, I have a folder with log files in a directory, and I have the directory set to allow directory listing. The folder is named `logs`. What I want to do is hide the logs folder, so if the user goes to the directory of the .htaccess which is also in the same directory as the logs folder, it won't show up in the directory listing. However, if the user adds `/logs` to the end of the URL, it will allow the user to view the contents. I tried this in my `.htaccess` file, which I placed in the same directory as the logs folder, but nothing happened.

```
  Options Indexes
  IndexIgnore logs .htaccess
```

Also, I only want to hide the logs folder in the same directory as the .htaccess, so if there is a subdirectory with a different name that has a folder named logs inside it, that folder won't be hidden.

Comment: This isnt possible. IndexIgnore only works for filenames and extensions.

Comment: try **Options -Indexes** instead of IndexIgnore

Comment: @starkeen Apparently nothing seems to happen with either option. I even placed a test file ending in ".log" and that doesn't disappear even with IndexIgnore after adding "*.log" to the end of the line.